# Conditional logic for VisualForce alert box

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to check at least one user is selected(checkbox checked) when clicking on Send Email button. How to have a conditional logic in the Command button?

```
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" id="checked"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!c.con.Email}" />
            <apex:column value="{!c.con.Phone}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!sendEmail}" onclick="if(!confirm('Do you want to send the email?')){return false;}" onComplete="window.top.location.reload()"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Solution trying:
Sending email to the select contact records. The above pageBlockTable will display all the contact records with provided SOQL query. Implemented using [Wrapper class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) to display contact records with checkboxes.

Now I am trying to validate whether the end user selected(checkboxes) at least one of the listed contacts before executing the sendEmail action. How can I approach that?

Comment: can you update your question trying your conditional logic?

Comment: Provided some explanation to the solution I am trying.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty conventional to do this validation at the server-side. In your controller:

```
public PageReference sendEmail() {
    Boolean atLeastOneSelected = false;
    for (WrapperClassName c : contacts) {
        if (c.selected) {
            atLeastOneSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (atLeastOneSelected) {
        ... do send ...
    } else {
        // You need an apex:pageMessages in the Visualforce to see this
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
                'Select at least one Contact'
                ));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Best not to interfere by defining your own `onComplete`; the return value of the controller method will drive  what the next page is with `null` meaning redisplay the current page.

You could do the check at the client-side in JavaScript, but then Visualforce gives you very little help and you have to be pretty good at JavaScript/DOM to do a good job.